# PivotFilters.Add not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply to a Pivot table a filter without looping and setting visibile=true for each element.

I've come out with this line of code:

```
Worksheets("DATI").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("ACCOUNT").PivotFilters.Add FilterType:=xlCaptionEquals, DataFilter:="ACCOUNT", Value1:=Filtro
```

Where Filtro is this variable

```
Filtro = Worksheets("Riconciliazione").Range("b2").Value
```

But I get a 448 Error - Named argument not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about the argument names of the function.

This is the description of the function. I don't see `FilterType` & `DataFilter`

```
Function Add(Type As XlPivotFilterType, [DataField], [Value1], [Value2], [Order], [Name], [Description], [MemberPropertyField]) As PivotFilter
```